# Fill PDF form using perl or node

Tags: forms, pdf

I need to fill PDF form, Which contains radio buttons too. I tried to fill it with perl, `CAM::PDF` module and with `node`, `pdf-fill-form` module.
In node, the radio's value is always undefined:

```
{
    name: 'Op1',
    page: 14,
    value: undefined,
    id: 983128,
    type: 'radio'
}
```

In perl, the object's value looks like this (if the first option is checked is S, second: XL, third: 2XL etc):

```
'V'=> bless({
    'gennum'=>0,
    'value'=>'S',
    'type'=>'label',
    'objnum'=>988
},
'CAM: : PDF: : Node')
```

If I change the **S** to **XL**, nothing happens in the PDF.

Has somebody any idea, How to fill the radio box?

Comment: Regarding CAM::PDF, you probably need to save it back. Are you doing that? Please [edit] your question and include the full program for both Perl and node.js. I don't know how the people in the node.js tag prefer it, but in the Perl tag we need a [mcve]. In your case, the full program makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I saved. Here is the node.js program: var pdfFillForm = require('pdf-fill-form');
var fs = require('fs');


var original_pdf = process.argv[2];
var input_json = process.argv[3];
var result = process.argv[4];

var formFields = pdfFillForm.readSync(original_pdf);

for (var item in formFields) {
 console.log(formFields[item]);
}

var mydata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(input_json, 'utf8'));

var pdf = pdfFillForm.writeSync(original_pdf,
 mydata, { "save": "pdf" } );
fs.writeFileSync(result, pdf);

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that. It's not readable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with node js npm pdf-fill-form module.
let say you are trying to set gender:
your radio button must be formed this way.

```
{ name: 'gender',
    page: 0,
    value: false,
    id: 65558,
    caption: 'male',
    type: 'radio' },
  { name: 'gender',
    page: 0,
    value: false,
    id: 65559,
    caption: 'female',
    type: 'radio' }
```

Here caption is the important one.
if you trying to set gender is male means just do this

```
{ gender: 'male'}
```